# Solve an equation system with implicit funtions

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations

> Show that the equation system
>
> $$x^2 + y^2 + 3u^2 + 4v^2 = 1$$
> $$x^2 + y^2 - u^2 - v^2 = 0$$
>
> can be solved by two positive functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ and calculate their partial derivatives.

I think that this is related to the implicit function theorem, but I do not see how I could solve this. Could you help me?

Comment: subtracting first equation from second, gives $4u^2+5v^2=1$ or $v^2=\frac{1-4u^2}{5}$ Now ...

Comment: But now $v$ depends on $u$ instead of $x,y$. I do not see your point

Comment: Plug @Qurultay 's hint into either equation. Then you can solve for $u$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Then you can solve for $v$ in terms of $u(x,y)$.

Comment: In fact, the system of equations is a non homogeneous system of equations in two unknowns $u^2$ and $v^2$. Solving this system will give you $u$ and $ v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtracting the second equation from the first yo get $4u^2+5v^2=1$. Now, keeping the second one, you have the system
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  4u^2  + 5v^2  = 1 \hfill \\
  u^2  + v^2  = x^2  + y^2  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
which get
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  4u^2  + 5v^2  = 1 \hfill \\
   - 4u^2  - 4v^2  =  - 4x^2  - 4y^2  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
Therefore, by adding the equation you get
$$
v^2  = 1 - 4x^2  - 4y^2 
$$
and now, you have
$$
u^2  = 5x^2  + 5y^2  - 1
$$
From these you can find $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$